# Flask: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python, flask

Im new to Python/Flask and wanted to set Cookies for my Website. When i open the Website i get this error.

The functions that are causing Problems:

```
def numberinstring(nr: int, cookie: str):
          
        visited = cookie.split(":")

        for door in visited:
                if nr == int(door):
                        return True
        return False

def handlecookie(resp: Response, nr: int):

        cookie = request.cookies.get("Besucht")

        if cookie is None:
                resp.set_cookie("Besucht", str(nr))
                return resp

        if numberinstring(nr, cookie):
                return resp

        resp.set_cookie("Besucht",cookie + ":" + str(nr))
        return resp
```

I am confused to why it doesent work as I checked if cookie is None in line 15.

The Traceback:

```
File "C:\Users\PJ\Desktop\Kalender\main.py", line 48, in start

if numberinstring(i, cookie):
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

File "C:\Users\PJ\Desktop\Kalender\main.py", line 12, in numberinstring

visited = cookie.split(":")
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: The `if cookie is None` should have worked, and prevents passing `None` to the `numberinstring` function. Are you sure those changes were properly applied and your server is up to date? You can be doubly-sure by going through a debugger or putting debug logs after the `.get` call, inside the `if None` check, and inside `numberinstring`.

Comment: It should be up to date, i haven't had that Problem before. Weird thing is this code worked fine a day ago with the only change being unrelated in the HTML file as why im confused it doesen't work now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request.cookies.get("Besucht")` will return None if there's no KEY with name "Besucht" so check if cookie has value before calling the split method.

```py
def numberinstring(nr: int, cookie: str):
      visited = ""
      if cookie:
          visited = cookie.split(":")

      for door in visited:
          if nr == int(door):
              return True
      return False
```

Comment: ...which should have been caught by the check `if cookie is None` before calling `numberinstring`. The OP's question was why their `is None` check isn't working.

Comment: @GinoMempin Do you want me to do the check before call numberinstring?

Comment: Re-read the question. The OP's code has a `if cookie is None` check after getting the value from the `cookies` dict and before calling `numberinstring`. It should have already handled the case of a None cookie. The OP's question was why that didn't already work.

Comment: Okay I just seeing it I think the user edited the question

Comment: Then the traceback should be updated because it's misleading.